# Better approach when obtaining multiple values from the same method at once

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following method which returns a tuple,

```
public Tuple<int, bool> GetStudentInformation(long stutID)
```

Called as,

```
Marks= GetStudentInformation((Id).Item1;
HasPassed= GetStudentInformation((Id).Item2;
```

This works fine as it is but I dont like that I call the same method twice to get item1 and item2, using Tuple is probably not the way ahead but any advice if c# has support to get two values returned over a single execution of the method?

Comment: At the very least you could assign the result of the call to a variable then get the `Item1` and `Item2` out to avoid a second call to the method.  Better yet is to use value tuples like `public (int, bool) Method()` and then you can do `var (marks, passed) = Method();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to save return value

```cs
Tuple<int, bool> info = GetStudentInformation(Id);

Marks = info.Item1;
HasPassed = info.Item2;
```

Answer (score 0):

example of a clearer way I prefer when using tuples:

```
public (int data1, bool data2) GetStudentInformation(Id) {
    return (123, true);
}

var studentInfo = GetStudentInformation(111);
Console.Write(studentInfo.data1);
Console.Write(studentInfo.data2);
```